# Spring CLI v2.1.0.RELEASE - encrypt -> NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring, encryption

when i run:

```
spring encrypt totallysecretpassword --key=insanity
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.cloud.cli.command.encrypt.BaseEncryptOptionHandler.option(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljoptsimple/OptionSpecBuilder;
>           at org.springframework.cloud.cli.command.encrypt.BaseEncryptOptionHandler.options(BaseEncryptOptionHandler.java:53)
>           at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.getParser(OptionHandler.java:68)
>           at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:83)
>           at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:54)
>           at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219)
>           at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171)
>           at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:63)
>           ... 8 more

i re-installed JCE as told here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-cli/

basically, what i want is this: 
https://blog.novatec-gmbh.de/encrypted-properties-spring/

but in 1.3.2 it was the same error, so i used the latest ... but still no success ... what am i missing ?

--
did not get to run 2.0.8's encrypt on my windows box, @jtim 's answer wored for me when doing that on an ubuntu-box !

Answer (score 4):

It is a breaking change from spring-boot-cli. Just wait for the release of a compatible version of spring-cloud-cli (the [request](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-cli/issues/81) of the new release).

Or you could [install](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-installing-spring-boot.html#getting-started-installing-the-cli) an older version of spring-boot-cli that doesn't have the change, such as [2.0.8.RELEASE](https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-cli/2.0.8.RELEASE/)

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into the same problem. 
Using Sdkman you can quickly downgrade to a version that works fine:

```
sdk ls springboot
sdk use springboot 2.0.8.RELEASE
spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2.0.0.RELEASE
```

Comment: Downgrading spring worked for me, I can now use the encrypt command with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use lower version of Spring boot cli. The following configuration worked for me:

Springboot cli version:  2.1.6.RELEASE

Create System variable,

`name: SPRING_HOME`

`value: C:\Users\zafrullahsyed\Downloads\spring-2.1.6.RELEASE`

Add the bin folder to System path: `%SPRING_HOME%\bin`

Open CMD as admin else the jars are not created on `spring-2.1.6.RELEASE\lib\ext` folder

Check the Spring --version

`Spring CLI v2.1.6.RELEASE`

Then install sping cloud plugin:

`spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2.1.0.RELEASE`

`spring encrypt mysecret --key foo`

Encrypted value: `1c656a1a4617146a7e76d977ca5fa2cfeb0afecc5655677193f53ab43578dd4d`

`spring decrypt --key foo 1c656a1a4617146a7e76d977ca5fa2cfeb0afecc5655677193f53ab43578dd4d`

Decrypted value:

mysecret

Answer (score 0):

I too bumped to this issue and here is what I did,

```
# Step 1: Download the binaries to install (https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-cli/)
$ wget https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-cli/2.0.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-cli-2.0.8.RELEASE-bin.tar.gz

# Step 2: Extract the tar.gz
$ tar xvf spring-boot-cli-2.0.8.RELEASE-bin.tar.gz

# Step 3: Enable execute permissions
$ chmod +x spring-2.0.8.RELEASE/bin/spring

# Install Spring Cloud
$ spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2.0.0.RELEASE

# Step 5: Add it to your PATH
$ cd spring-2.0.8.RELEASE/bin
$ echo "PATH=$(pwd):\$PATH" >> .bashrc or  .zshrc
```

This usually works for Mac and any Linux based systems. I have personally tried this on Mac and Linux Mint

Output:

```
$ spring encrypt totallysecretpassword --key=insanity
f5a7944890c871ef58971eeaf123bbc750727b012cce8f7072def5bf71b000fb00089e106775ac0306b5f15b8f17d233
```

Hope this helps someone.